# Concatenate 'A' with SQL query

Tags: sql

How to do I use a SQL query having one field, and if the field contains values between '90' AND '99', the result will concatenate A to it?

The final output will look like this.

```
91A
92A
93A
94A
95A
```

I tried following.

```
SELECT
tblgrade.fld1stGrade ,'A'
FROM
tblgrade WHERE tblgrade.fld1stGrade BETWEEN '90' AND '99'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following if your implementation is in SQL Server.

```
SELECT
tblgrade.fld1stGrade +'A'
FROM
tblgrade WHERE CAST(tblgrade.fld1stGrade as int) >= 90 
and cast(tblgrade.fld1stGrade as int) <= 99;
```

For MySQL implementation use following.

```
select concat(tblgrade.fld1stGrade, 'A') from tblgrade
where tblgrade.fld1stGrade >= 90 and tblgrade.fld1stGrade <= 99;
```

For multiple category comparison in MySQL, use something like below.

```
select 
case
  when tblgrade.fld1stGrade >=90 and tblgrade.fld1stGrade <= 99 
     then concat(tblgrade.fld1stGrade, 'A')
  when tblgrade.fld1stGrade >=80 and tblgrade.fld1stGrade <= 89 
     then concat(tblgrade.fld1stGrade, 'B')
  when tblgrade.fld1stGrade >=70 and tblgrade.fld1stGrade <= 79 
     then concat(tblgrade.fld1stGrade, 'C')
  else concat(details, 'D')
  end
  as Grade
from supportContacts;
```

Comment: actually my fld1sGrade is Varchar so there's nothing to worried about the datatype, and i tried your query and it is not working
error:[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(4)) +'A'

Comment: sir your code is correct but the field has also values like '80' and '89' so i want to output also like this
91A
92A
93A
94A
89B
88B
86B

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT tblgrade.fld1stGrade + 'A' AS letter_grade FROM tblgrade 
WHERE tblgrade.fld1stGrade BETWEEN '90' AND '99'
```

Comment: nope this is not what i ask, the final output would be like this 
fld1stGrading
91A
92A
93A
94A
so no need to change the field name using AS.